# Display username in user.html.twig template

Tags: theming, users

How can I show the display name from my theme's user.html.twig template?

I have tried `{{ content.display_name }}`, `{{ content.field_display_name }}` and I am open to setting a Twig variable or preprocessing in the `.theme` file, but I need help.